# WPF Handlers for user control sub-controls

Tags: wpf, user-controls, handlers

I have defined a user control to represent a tab item comprising of a few buttons. When I create an instance of the user tab item I would like to define click handlers for button clicks.
e.g. for

> ```
> <TabItem >
>    <my:Tab1/>   
> </TabItem>
> ```

For Button1 and Button2 within Tab1 I would like to define something like

> ```
> <TabItem >
>     <my:Tab1 Button1:Click="button1_Click" Button2:Click="button2_Click"/>
> </TabItem>
> ```
>
> Naturally, the above doesn't work. Does anyone know how I can achieve this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried using routed events?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be done by routed events on you user control that rise buttons click event handler or by using commands. [This is probably a same case as yours](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4199312/how-can-a-button-click-on-a-usercontrol-execute-a-method-in-the-containing-windo)

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. So in Tab1::button1_Click() I raise a routed event? How do I declare a handler in my main application that owns the instance of the user control?